# GCP Firestore pagination with node.js - query cursor without snapshots

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a bit confused with a documentation, where it says to use "[Use a document snapshot to define the query cursor](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor)".

I have an API `http://localhost:3001/products?page=3&perPage=2` where I want to provide a specific page to retrieve defined amount of data.

`.startAfter(page * perPage - 1)` is ignored and it just pops out the first data as by default.

Did I miss something ?

```js
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('======  ======')
  const db = new Firestore({ projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID })

  const page = Number(req?.query?.page) || 1
  const perPage = Number(req?.query?.perPage) || 4

  const results = []

  const query = db.collection('orphans')
    .select('sku')
    .orderBy('sku')
    .limit(perPage)
    .startAfter(page * perPage)

  const collection = await query.get()

  collection.forEach(doc => results.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
  console.log(`Returned ${results.length} out of ${collection.size}`)
  console.log('First item:', results[0].id)
  console.log('Last item:', results[results.length - 1].id)

  return res.json({
    status: 'OK',
    data: results
  })
})
```

Console output:

```sh
======  ======
page: 3
perPage: 2
Returned 2 out of 2
First item: 000_TEST_MASS_001
Last item: 000_TEST_MASS_002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `startAfter` as an offset, passing in the number of items of how many documents to skip. That's not how `startAfter` works.

Firestore pagination is based on knowing the document that you want to start retrieving after, known as the anchor object - or a cursor. So instead of passing in a count, you're supposed to pass in either a snapshot of the document to start after, or the `sku` (the field you sort on) value and the document id of the document to start after.

---

Since you're running on Node.js, there **is** a function that does what you want called `offset` (see [reference docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#offset)). When you use this operation though, be aware that you're charged for reading all documents that were skipped by the offset too.

---

I recommend also checking out some of these previous [questions on Firebase pagination and offsets](https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+pagination+offset).

Comment: thank you for clarifying the approach. I tried to avoid "offset" like you said, because of the fees. I will try that with the snapshots of documentID and SKU, I will give my feedback  after testing.

Comment: How would you actually use a cursor by "sku" without having to use a snapshot ? Passing an object doesn't seem to work

Comment: You need to pass an array of values, not an object. See the example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#web-version-8_4